# Guile scheme cond ERROR: Wrong type to apply

Tags: scheme, guile

It is not clear to me why this cond gives Wrong type to apply error.

scheme@(guile-user) [12]>(cond ((equal? "i" "i") => (display "yay")))

yay

ERROR: In procedure #:

ERROR: Wrong type to apply: #

scheme@(guile-user) [12]>(cond ((string= "i" "i") => (display "yay")))

yay

ERROR: In procedure #:

ERROR: Wrong type to apply: #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual syntax for `cond` is as follows:

```
(cond ((equal? "i" "i")
       (display "yay")))
; prints yay
```

We use `=>` when we want to pass the result of the condition as a parameter to a function that gets executed, for instance:

```
(cond ((equal? "i" "i") 
       => display))
; prints #t
```

In the above code the condition evaluates to `#t`, and `#t` is passed as a parameter to `display`, which prints it.